# Convert dropdown form into selectable button

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I have the following dropdown form :

```
<select value="<?php echo $salesman; ?>" class="form-control" name="data[Invoice][salesman]" placeholder="Salesman">
    <option value="Unset" <?= ($invoice['Invoice']['salesman']) == 'Unset' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Please Choose</option>
    <option value="Person 1" <?= ($invoice['Invoice']['salesman']) == 'Person 1' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Person 1</option>
    <option value="Person 2" <?= ($invoice['Invoice']['salesman']) == 'Person 2' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Person 2</option>
    <option value="Person 3" <?= ($invoice['Invoice']['salesman']) == 'Person 3' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Person 3</option>
    <option value="None" <?= ($invoice['Invoice']['salesman']) == 'None' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>None</option>
</select>
```

and the SQL code to parse it(snippet) :

```
$salesman = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, trim( $data['data']['Invoice']['salesman'] ) );
```

How would I convert the dropdown to be instead images as in the image I have uploaded?  The end result would allow the user to click on multiple people, and have that information stored, and retrieved properly when viewing the page.  The people selected will have their button highlighted as such with a custom image.

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: I guess you would need ajax to store the info, or do you have a submit sort of button?

Comment: I do have a submit button, and i can select a user(single) now, I want to modify the sql code to store multiple users, if modifications are needed, but the code as is, is working - only showing the parts relating to the question though

Comment: You ask in your if clause `($invoice['Invoice']['salesman']) == 'Person 2'` what whould be in the variable if you have Person 1 AND Person 2 selected?

Answer (score 1):

In order to allow your form to handle multiple values instead of just a single value for salesman, you would need to pass it an array of values

(e.g. `$invoice['Invoice']['salespeople'] = ['Person 1', 'Person 2'];`)

In this case you could represent the data on your form using checkboxes like this:

```
<label>Person 1</label><input type="checkbox" name="salespeople[]" value="Person 1" 
    <?= in_array('Person 1', $invoice['Invoice']['salespeople']) ? 'checked' : '' ?>>

<label>Person 2</label><input type="checkbox" name="salespeople[]" value="Person 2" 
    <?= in_array('Person 2', $invoice['Invoice']['salespeople']) ? 'checked' : '' ?>>

<label>Person 3</label><input type="checkbox" name="salespeople[]" value="Person 3" 
    <?= in_array('Person 3', $invoice['Invoice']['salespeople']) ? 'checked' : '' ?>>

<label>None</label><input type="checkbox" name="salespeople[]" value="None" 
    <?= empty($invoice['Invoice']['salespeople']) ? 'checked' : '' ?>>
```

Then when you submit your form, the script that handles the submission would get an array of salespeople rather than a single salesman.

It is possible to style the labels+checkboxes as toggle buttons using CSS; you can google for various examples of this.

Comment: You would probably also want to add some way of handling "None" selected when one or more other values were also selected. You could uncheck other values using JS, or just ignore a "None" selection along with other selections on the server side.

Comment: How do I pull the values as an array?  Right now I can only deal with a single item, and have it coded as such : $salesman = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, trim( $data['data']['Invoice']['salesman'] ) );